# How to keep files in development branch and not export them to master branch?

Tags: git, github

Newbie to web dev, I am trying to understand how deal **production** and **development** branches with git and github.

I understand that having a master branch for **production** and another branch for **development** is a good practice.

However, I do not understand how to deal with gitignore.

There are somes files (**production**) that I don't want to export to github, like *.env* for instance. I assume these files are specified in the gitignore file, and will remain on my production server.

But how am I suppose to deal with files that I want to keep on my **development** branch, be able to pull from my github repo but no merge with my **production** branch on my github repo too ? I am thinking of my local sqlite database for instance. This does not seem to be handled with gitignore.

Comment: "I understand that having a master branch for production and another branch for development is a good practice." - not everyone shares that viewpoint. But setting that aside - is your question just "How do I avoid committing a SQLite database file to Git?"

Answer (score 0):

Having a `production` and a `development` branch is a workflow and should be seen as one best practice out of many alternative best practices and is not something that is required in git. It seems as if the best practice you have read about is similar to the popular GitFlow workflow that you can read more about here: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow. But remember that this is a philosophy on how to use git, not something git require.

In GitFlow and similar workflows you should not commit anything to the `development` branch that is not intended to eventually be included in the `production` branch. So in your case it is unlikely the case that you want to push your database to any branch. Instead, ignore in the the `.gitignore` and share it between different `dev` systems using other methods. For example a shared drive, a cloud storage or have a script that sets it up and populate it with test data from an API.